# Ubuntu 16.04 Nvidia GTX 1080

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, kernel

I can't get my nVidia driver to work.

Here is some info:

> Ubuntu 16.04 kernel 4.13.0-43-generic Nvidia GTX 1080 gcc-5

What did i tried:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Following errors occured:

```
Building initial module for 4.13.0-43-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/nvidia-396.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.13.0-43-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-396/396.24/build/make.log for more information.
Setting up libcuda1-396 (396.24-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1) ...
Setting up libjansson4:amd64 (2.7-3) ...
Setting up libvdpau1:amd64 (1.1.1-3ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libxnvctrl0:amd64 (396.24-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1) ...
Setting up mesa-vdpau-drivers:amd64 (17.2.8-0ubuntu0~16.04.1) ...
Setting up nvidia-opencl-icd-396 (396.24-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1) ...
Setting up bbswitch-dkms (0.8-3ubuntu1) ...
Loading new bbswitch-0.8 DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 4.13.0-43-generic
Building initial module for 4.13.0-43-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/bbswitch-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.13.0-43-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/bbswitch/0.8/build/make.log for more information.
Setting up nvidia-prime (0.8.2) ...
Setting up screen-resolution-extra (0.17.1.1~16.04.1) ...
Setting up nvidia-settings (396.24-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1) ...
Setting up vdpau-driver-all:amd64 (1.1.1-3ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.11) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-43-generic
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
```

`sudo vim /var/crash/nvidia-396.0.crash`:

```
 ProblemType: Package
DKMSBuildLog:
 DKMS make.log for nvidia-396-396.24 for kernel 4.13.0-43-generic (x86_64)
 di 22 mei 2018  8:27:09 CEST
 make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-43-generic'
 cc1: internal compiler error: Bus error
 Please submit a full bug report,
 with preprocessed source if appropriate.
 See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs> for instructions.
 cc1: internal compiler error: Bus error
 Please submit a full bug report,
 with preprocessed source if appropriate.
 See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs> for instructions.
   SYMLINK /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-396/396.24/build/nvidia/nv-kernel.o
   SYMLINK /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-396/396.24/build/nvidia-modeset/nv-modeset-kernel.o

 The C compiler 'cc' does not appear to be able to
 create executables.  Please make sure you have
 your Linux distribution's gcc and libc development
 packages installed.

 *** Failed CC sanity check. Bailing out! ***

 /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-396/396.24/build/Kbuild:180: recipe for target 'cc_sanity_check' failed
 make[2]: *** [cc_sanity_check] Error 1
 make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
 Makefile:1550: recipe for target '_module_/var/lib/dkms/nvidia-396/396.24/build' failed
 make[1]: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/nvidia-396/396.24/build] Error 2
 make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-43-generic'
 Makefile:79: recipe for target 'modules' failed
 make: *** [modules] Error 2
DKMSKernelVersion: 4.13.0-43-generic
Date: Tue May 22 08:27:34 2018
Package: nvidia-396 396.24-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1
PackageVersion: 396.24-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1
SourcePackage: nvidia-graphics-drivers-396
Title: nvidia-396 396.24-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1: nvidia-396 kernel module failed to build
ApportVersion: 2.20.1-0ubuntu2.17
Architecture: amd64
DistroRelease: Ubuntu 16.04
InstallationDate: Installed on 2018-02-19 (91 days ago)
InstallationMedia: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS "Xenial Xerus" - Release amd64 (20170801)
ProcCpuinfoMinimal:
 processor      : 7
 vendor_id      : GenuineIntel
 cpu family     : 6
 model          : 158
 model name     : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700K CPU @ 4.20GHz
 stepping       : 9
 microcode      : 0x84
 cpu MHz                : 4400.002
 cache size     : 8192 KB
 physical id    : 0
 siblings       : 8
 core id                : 3
 cpu cores      : 4
 apicid         : 7
 initial apicid : 7
 fpu            : yes
 fpu_exception  : yes
 cpuid level    : 22
 wp             : yes
 flags          : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault invpcid_single pti retpoline intel_pt rsb_ctxsw spec_ctrl tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp
 bugs           : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass
```

`sudo vim /var/lib/dkms/bbswitch/0.8/build/make.log`:

```
DKMS make.log for bbswitch-0.8 for kernel 4.13.0-43-generic (x86_64)
wo 30 mei 2018  8:41:46 CEST
make -C /lib/modules/4.13.0-43-generic/build M="$(pwd)" modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-43-generic'
cc1: internal compiler error: Bus error
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs> for instructions.
cc1: internal compiler error: Bus error
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs> for instructions.
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/bbswitch/0.8/build/bbswitch.o
cc1: internal compiler error: Bus error
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs> for instructions.
scripts/Makefile.build:323: recipe for target '/var/lib/dkms/bbswitch/0.8/build/bbswitch.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/bbswitch/0.8/build/bbswitch.o] Error 1
Makefile:1550: recipe for target '_module_/var/lib/dkms/bbswitch/0.8/build' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/bbswitch/0.8/build] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-43-generic'
Makefile:13: recipe for target 'default' failed
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

Comment: FYI the graphics-driver ppa provides the 396.24 driver for 16.04

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! It looks like the C compiler on your system was damaged. Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `which -a cc gcc as cpp ld`, `cc --version`, `gcc --version`, `as --version`, `cpp --version` and `ld --version`? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

why using autoinstall command go to "software and updates" and then "additional drivers" apply changes. Or you install run file from nvidia website (not that recommended tho, repo one is always tested). ubuntu 18.04 has much better nvidia support in 16.04 there were also some changes you have to make in grub like nomodeset even after installing drivers.